# What is the different between 'true branch executed' and 'branch executed' in the colver?

Tags: java, junit, clover

I'm using clover plugin for check my java code test coverage.[image]

I wrote unit test for all the lines. When I click on the red line, it shows 'true branch executed 2 time and branch executed 0 times'.What does that mean? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You did not test the implicit else branch.